# How to save 8 channels np.concatenated image to image file for training?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

Can I save img_concatenate and mask_concatenate to image file(like jpg,tiff...),or type conform to  flow_from_directory(directory)

but they have 8 channels and 6 channels, I need to concatenate 6img for Datagenerator

```
img_concatenate = np.concatenate(six_img, axis=3) #(1, 512, 512, 8)
mask_concatenate = np.concatenate(six_mask, axis=3) #(1, 512, 512, 6)
```

I'm facing some problem on flow_from_directory,it only receive path,no receive concatenated image list.

Comment: save as `npy` or `npz` file

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I will try that and try to modify generator,thank you